# Spring-boot - add hibernate mapping file to entity manager

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm migrating legacy app to Spring-boot and have to integrate an hibernate named query mapping file (previously configured in persitence.xml file).

I've come out with a solution with an

```html
...
@Autowired
private DataSource dataSource;

@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setDataSource(dataSource);

    //...

    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingResources("META-INF/named-queries.hbm.xml");

    return sessionFactoryBean;
}
```

But i'm ending having an entityManager bean and a sessionFactory bean in my application!

is it a good solution according to you?
Is there a way to add somehow the hibernate mapping file (named-query.hbm.xml) to the entityManager without using the sessionFactory bean?

Thanks in advance for you suggestions

** EDIT **
fro JB Nizet's suggestion, also come up with another solution

```html
@Bean
public LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {
    LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();

    entityManagerFactory.setDataSource(dataSource);

    // ...

    entityManagerFactory.setMappingResources("META-INF/named-queries.hbm.xml");

    return entityManagerFactory;
}
```

and in my DAO/Service, i can still get hibernate session with:

```html
private Session getSession() {
        //return this.sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        return this.entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }
```

But if someone nows if we can do the same thing with spring-boot auto-config with properties, it's welcomed!

Comment: You could place your named query using annotations on Entities java file.

Comment: Why don't you set the mapping resources on the LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean instead? http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/orm/jpa/LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.html#setMappingResources-java.lang.String...-

Comment: @Jay Thanks for you reply Jay. As mentionned, I'm using a legacy code and i have to integrate the mapping file as it is.

Comment: @JBNizet Thanks for your suggestion JB. Is it possible to set mapping resource using spring-boot properties (and auto config mecanism) or do i have to define the **LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean**  myself?

Comment: Define your `mapping-file` in a `persistence.xml`., and ditch the custom configured one. Or migrate your `named-queries.hbm.xml` to an `orm.xml` (the JPA equivalent of this file) and place it in `META-INF` and it will be loaded automatically.

Answer (score 7):

Put the *.hbm.xml files under the src/main/resources folder and Spring Boot can automatically scan for them.

If you want to specify the location in the application.properties file, define them to the spring.jpa.mapping-resources attribute.

```
spring.jpa.mapping-resources=hibernate/MyMapping.hbm.xml,hibernate/MyMapping2.hbm.xml
```

Tested in SpringBoot 2.1.3, following is the folder structure

```
src/main/resources/hibernate : Store all the *.hbm.xml files
src/main/resources/application.properties : define the spring boot properties
```

And if you want to get the hibernate session in your Dao classes, define them as follows:

```java
@Repository
@Transactional
public class XxxDao {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManager entityManager;

    private Session getSession() {
        return entityManager.unwrap(Session.class);
    }
...
}
```

Comment: For me (using hibernate 5.5) it works with `spring.jpa.mapping-resources` property only. Putting the files into `src/main/resources` without listing them in the property did not work.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Autowired
private ResourceLoader rl;


@Bean
public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() throws IOException {
    LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactoryBean = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();
    sessionFactoryBean.setMappingLocations(loadResources());
}

public Resource[] loadResources() {
    Resource[] resources = null;
    try {
        resources = ResourcePatternUtils.getResourcePatternResolver(rl)
            .getResources("classpath:/hibernate/*.hbm.xml");
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return resources;
}
```

Comment: This code doesn't compile. sessionFactory() is not returning anything.