# How to add hibernate mapping file to Spring boot configuration?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-boot

I'm trying to move a huge query to the external file (xml). I'm using Spring boot with Spring Data JPA. It was easy with persistence.xml, but I have only application.properties here.

Is there a easy way to do this?

I created orm.xml, added query there, but it looks like Spring Boot is not recognizing it.

Comment: Similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536200/spring-boot-add-hibernate-mapping-file-to-entity-manager there are some tips in the comments, it might be useful