# Spring boot test not picking up hbm.xml files from src/main/resources

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-boot-test

We have a project on spring-boot version 1.5.2.RELEASE.

We need to work on hibernate named queries in xml (Named queries in java annotation is not an option for us).

For this purpose we have added all our `hbm.xml` files (which contains these named queries) in `src/main/resources` directory.

This is not a problem when our application is running. The named queries gets picked up correctly.

However, when we write the integration test cases, it is not able to recognize the named queries.

We get:

> Named Query not found exception

Below is our test case code:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest( webEnvironment = SpringBootTest.WebEnvironment.RANDOM_PORT)
public class MyIntegrationTest {
    @Autowired
    private TestRestTemplate template;

    @Test 
    public void checkRestService() throws Exception {
        ResponseEntity<String> response = template.getForEntity("/hello/1", String.class);
        assertTrue(response.getStatusCodeValue() == 200);
    }
}
```

If we copy the `hbm.xml` files in `src/test/resources directory`, the `hbm.xml` files gets picked up correctly and the test runs correctly.

Is there anyway that the xml files gets picked up directly from `src/main/resouces` folder and we don't have to copy these files?

Comment: An [asked question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536200/spring-boot-add-hibernate-mapping-file-to-entity-manager) that may help you.

Comment: Thanks for posting the link for similar question. However, we are able to use Hibernate SessionFactory and use named queries from hbm.xml files correctly in the main application. The problem is only while writing integration test cases.

Answer (score 0):

I got the same problem as you in Spring Boot 2.1.3 and solved by moving the application.properties file from the src/test/resources folder to src/main/resources folder and renaming it to application-test.properties

Following is my case:

My Spring Boot 2.1.3 application has following folder structure:

```
src/main
     +-- java (applcation java files)
     +-- resources
            +-- hibernate/MyMapping.hbm.xml
            +-- hibernate/MyMapping2.hbm.xml
            +-- application.properties (define the default / base attributes needed for my application)
            +-- application-dev.properties (define the development environment settings)
src/test
    +-- java (testing java files)
    +-- resources
            +-- application.properties (define the testing attributes)
```

Whenever i run the Test Case in Eclipse / maven, there is always the error:

> Named Query not found exception

I resolved this by:

1. Move the src/test/resources/application.properties file to the src/main/resources/application-test.properties
2. In the src/main/resources/application.properties, define following attribute:

```
spring.jpa.mapping-resources=hibernate/MyMapping.hbm.xml,hibernate/MyMapping2.hbm.xml
```

3. Add the annotation `@ActiveProfile("test")` to all the test classes so that it will first load the application-test.properties file in the src/main/resources folder

After this, the test cases of my SpringBoot 2 application can run without any problem in both the Eclipse and maven command line.

My gut feeling is that the Spring Boot / Hibernate uses the location of the first loaded application.properties as the base to scan / locate all the hbm files. This might related to the classloader