# Using orm.xml in tests of SpringBoot 2.0

Tags: spring, jpa, spring-boot, spring-boot-test

I have a SpringBoot 2.0 application, and I've decided to mix annotations and XML configuration using `orm.xml`. So, I've put `orm.xml` (JPA file with XML configuration) in `resources/META-INF`, and, when starting the application, it's taken into account and everything is good, it works like a charm.

However, when running integration tests (which use an in-memory database), `orm.xml` seems to be completely ignored, as the test fails with an exception related to a missing mapping, mapping which I've written in `orm.xml` (an embeddable entity).

Here's how a test looks like:

```
package hello;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.jdbc.AutoConfigureTestDatabase;
import org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.orm.jpa.DataJpaTest;
import org.springframework.boot.test.context.SpringBootTest;
import org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringRunner;

@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DataJpaTest
public class ApplicationTests {

    @Test
    public void contextLoads() {
    }

}
```

I've also tried `@AutoConfigureTestDatabase` instead of `@DataJpaTest`, but with no success.

What should I change, in order for the integration test to load `orm.xml`?

Comment: is it in `persistence.xml`? or whatever excuse for a "standard" Spring use?

Comment: Check this  .... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32536200/spring-boot-add-hibernate-mapping-file-to-entity-manager

Answer (score 0):

I had to migrate some integration tests that used an in-memory database to SpringBoot2 and in order to have access to the "orm.xml" file in the tests I just copied it from "src/main/resources/META-INF/orm.xml" to "src/**test**/resources/META-INF/orm.xml".

Answer (score -1):

I was using spring with junit (not spring boot) and I used to annotate the test class like this :

`@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = { "appContextTest.xml" })`

and inside the appContextTest.xml , I have the import :

`<import resource="classpath:config-test.xml" />`

EDIT : the file contents are like follows (it has the Datasource definition and hibernate properties :

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="oracle.jdbc.pool.OracleDataSource">
    <property name="URL" value="jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:serv"/>
    <property name="user" value="us"/>
    <property name="password" value="pass"/>
</bean>
.

.

.
<bean id="sessionFactory"
    class="org.springframework.orm.hibernate3.annotation.AnnotationSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />

    <property name="hibernateProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.bytecode.use_reflection_optimizer">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.format_sql">true</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.query.factory_class">org.hibernate.hql.classic.ClassicQueryTranslatorFactory</prop> 
        </props>
    </property>
```

`
... I don't know if that helps or no

Comment: I've tried this, but it doesn't work since the <import> tag imports XML bean definitions, while orm.xml is a JPA file, and therefore unrelated to Spring.